# Incorrect password or username in login form in cakephp

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, sha1, cakephp-2.x

I don't know why am still getting invalid username or password while I have all the codes and my database. Also the user is already registered but cannot login.

AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller{

    public $components = array(
        /*'DebugKit.Toolbar',*/
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Model: User.php

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('SimplePasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'Username' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            ),
            'The username already exists'=>array(
                'rule'=>array('isUnique'),
                'message'=>'The username already exists!'
            ),
        ),
        'Password' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            ),
            'Match passwords'=>array(
                'rule'=>'matchPasswords',
                'message'=>'The password does not match'
            ),
        ),
        'Confirm_Password' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
            ),
        ),
    );


    function matchPasswords($data){

        if ($data['Password'] == $this->data['User']['Confirm_Password']) {

            return TRUE;
        }
        $this->invalidate('Confirm_Password', 'The password does not match');
        return FALSE;
    }

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (!parent::beforeSave($options)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['Password'])) {
            $hasher = new SimplePasswordHasher();
            $this->data[$this->alias]['Password'] = $hasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['Password']);
        }
        return true;
    } 
}
```

Controller: UsersController.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array('Session');    

    var $name = 'Users';
    var $helpers = array('Form');

    // Placeholder for login_form, required by CakePHP to see the login_form view
    function login_form() { }

    public function beforeFilter () {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('user', 'login');
    }

    public function login(){
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect username or password'));
        }
    }

    public function logout() {

        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function done() {

        $this->set('framework', 'CakePHP');

    }

    public function user(){

        if($this->request->is('post')) {

            $this->User->create();

            if($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The information has been sent successfully!');
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));

                $this->redirect('done');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View: login.ctp

```
<h4>LOGIN HERE</h4>
    <?php
    echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('Username');
    echo $this->Form->input('Password',array('type' => 'password'));
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the default field names CakePHP is expecting. Therefore, you have to include them in your `AuthComponent` configuration.

Try the following:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public $components = array(
        /*'DebugKit.Toolbar',*/
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'users',
                'action' => 'login'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'fields' => array(
                        'username' => 'Username',
                        'password'=>'Password'
                    ),
                ),
            )
        )
    );
}
```

These should match the field names in your `users` table and in your views.

**EDIT**

Also, make sure your password field in the database is long enough to store the hashed password. The default algorithm used by CakePHP is SHA1, which produces a 160 bit (40 character) hash. A `VARCHAR 255` should be more than enough to store this string.

See:

- [Configuring Authentication handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers) in Cookbook 2.x | Authentication

Comment: Please post your `users` table `CREATE` statement.

Comment: It's done by issuing `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` If you are unable to do this, just post the field names and the data types used, in particular `users.Username` and `users.Password`.

Comment: ID INT,
Username Varchar,
Password Varchar

Comment: What length? `VARCHAR(10)`, `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: ID INT(11), Username Varchar(255), Password Varchar(20)

Comment: `VARCHAR(20)` is not enough to store the hash. See my edit.